# Httpclient wiretap logging hide Authorization in log

Tags: java, authentication, logging, httpclient

At the moment I am using

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient
  .create()
  .wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient", 
    LogLevel.INFO, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL);
```

to log back the response and request but I would like to hide the header *Authorization:* from log
is it passable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For logging you can add custom exchange filter to webClient

```
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(logResponse())
    }

    private ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {
                logHeaders(response);
                logBody(response);
        });
    }

    private void logHeaders(ClientResponse response) {
        //here you can decide what kind of header do you need append to logs
        response.headers().asHttpHeaders().forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> log.debug("{}={}", name, value)));
    }

    private static Mono<ClientResponse> logBody(ClientResponse response) {
       // log body
    }
```

Comment: its a good solution but i am still struggling to log out request and response body.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with the proposed solution ... how to log the request body ?

Comment: @Dave  same as resposne by using `ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor`

Comment: @viking your `logBody` function works at logging out the response body, since you can extract the raw body, but it doesn't really work that way for the request. There is no way of accessing the request body of a `ClientRequest` when you access it via `ExhangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor()`.